# Recorded Video Orientation Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, orientation

In my app i record and save videos using AVCapture/AssetsLibrary.When i record in portrait the orientation of the recorded video is ok but when i record in landscape the orientation of the recorded video is 90 degree which is bad.I need help with this issue please.
My code is..

In my appDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

    if(self.window.rootViewController){
        UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return orientations;
}
```

and in myViewController.m

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Capture Session orientation

```
AVCaptureConnection *CaptureConnection = [MovieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([CaptureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;

    [CaptureConnection setVideoOrientation:orientation];
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: How are you configuring the orientation of the capture session?

Answer (score 0):

Sets the CaptureVideoOrientation.i.e:

```
AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation =AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight
```

Answer (score 0):

The **rotation metadata** is saved by the mobile recording device together with the .mp4 or .mov video.

It can have 4 values: 0, 90, 180 and 270:

[image: Rotation Metadata in Video Files Created by Mobile Devices]

Image courtesy of [Rotation Metadata in Video Files Created by Mobile Devices](https://blog.addpipe.com/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/)

If the player you're using supports the rotation metadata you'll see portrait video (90°) shown as portrait. If it doesn't you'll see it as landscape.

Players that do not support it (list form link above):

- Firefox 42
- Opera on Mac
- Media Player Classic